# How to remove/delete an emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

I have multiple emulators and need to delete some of these.

How do I delete an emulator?

I found this:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager

I executed the command "flutter emulator" and got:

```
> Pixel_2_API_29     • Pixel 2 API 29     • Google • android  
Pixel_2_API_29_2   • Pixel 2 API 29 2   • Google • android  
flutter_emulator   • flutter emulator   • Google • android  
flutter_emulator_2 • flutter emulator 2 • Google • android
```

I then tried:

```
android delete avd -n Pixel_2_API_29
```

And other combinations, but got the errors:

```
Could not find a command named "android".
```

or:

```
Could not find a command named "delete".
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need to remove these using the Android Virtual Device Manager (AVD).
Open Android Studio and select Tools > AVD Manager

This will display a list of emulators you have set up. You will then be able to click the down pointing arrow on the right side which will then give you a delete option.

[image]

Comment: I have done this, and it seems to work. A bit disappointing that it can't just be done in a simple way through powershell inside VS Code. 
Appreciate your answer very much!

Comment: the question is about VS Code, not Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

The user guide [avdmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager) page you hyperlinked specifies how to delete avds.
If you don't know the name of the emulator you want to get rid of you can do a first

```
avdmanager list
```

then after

```
avdmanager delete avd -n emulator_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can (now?) delete the emulator using the avdmanager provided in the android SDK command-line tools. It requires the name of the emulator to delete (usually flutter_emulator, flutter_emulator_2, etc. if you don't specify a name on creation). You can check the id by executing `flutter emulator`. Then use the command below to delete the emulator you no longer need.

```
path_to_android_sdk\tools\bin\avdmanager delete avd -n emulator_id
```